# Is C > Am > Em in the key of E minor or in the Key of E phrygian?

Tags: songwriting

I am writing a song with the verse going from C > Am > Em > Em. . I can't think of any other pop/rock songs that use this progression and if anyone can think of any please share as this would be very helpful right now. So I suppose the progression could be either E minor or E phrygian. If the vocal melody above these chords was to exclude the F/F# note would the listener ever feel like there was an implied tonality?

Comment: Could be Em, C, Am or even G, in my opinion...

Comment: wouldn't the piece either need to begin or end in Aminor or Gmajor for those two to be valid options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the chords could be taken from E phrygian, it would be very uncommon to say that the given progression is in E phrygian. The reason is that the character note in phrygian is the b2, which would be F in this case, and since the note F does not show up anywhere, the most common interpretation would be to say that the progression is in E minor.

The story would be different if there were a melody over these chords which uses the note F. But if neither F nor F# are used in the melody, this progression is most likely in E minor.

Generally, a mode other than major and minor is only perceived if the chords and/or the melody feature the mode's character note. E.g., it doesn't make much musical sense to say that the progression C-G-C is in C lydian (with the #4, i.e. F#, as character note), even though the chord tones are all part of C lydian.

Comment: hmmm, interesting. I like your thinking. I  think I can agree with you and discard Ephrygian as an option now which is great. But can you discard C major from from the options?

Comment: @armani: Well, what do *you* hear as the "home" chord here? Of course, those 3 chords are also part of C major, A minor, G major, ... But I hear E minor as the key, mainly because the progression leads to the Em chord, where it stays for two bars.

Comment: That is just the thing, I don't know. I guess it could be both? Even though there are two bars of Eminor at the end, I can't say that this is sufficient for saying Eminor, yet I can't say just because it starts with C and that all the chords are from C that it is in C major either. I guess there really is no answer?

Comment: @armani: Since the chords occur in several keys, one could keep arguing. Eventually, it's in the ears/head of the listener, but I dare to say that most musically trained people would perceive that progression to be in the key of E minor. But since it's *your* composition, *you* are the one to decide, and there is not definite right or wrong. As a hint, try to add an F to the melody somewhere to make it fit. Then try the same with F#. My guess is that it will be easier to make the F# sound good, which would imply E minor rather than C major.

Answer (score 0):

Could be either. Or it could be useful to consider it staying in C major.    What does the melody do?  Any F# notes?

Comment: I wrote it purposefully trying to exclude them so the listener wouldn't know but now I am not sure where to take the song. Have a listen to what I have so far here https://ufile.io/7jqrt
There is a quick short modulation to Dminor at the end before the chorus comes in. I don't know where to go from there. I suppose now there are 3 possibles for the chorus. Eminor, Ephrygian or stay in Dminor after the bridge? what would you do?

Comment: @armani congratz on that piece of music. I can see you've gone about it exactly the right way; following your ears and trying to understand why what you've written feels the way it does. I was originally going to just write a comment, but this warrants a proper answer which I'll probably write tomorrow. In short, you're in Em and then modulating to Cmaj (yes, despite the B flat). Don't get too carried away by the idea of being "in" a mode. Unless writing very strictly nodal music as a choice, it's much more useful to just know what the key centre is. A key is NOT a scale.  Again  great work!

Answer (score -1):

Seems more like C, although E Phrygian contains the same notes exactly. When it gets written on the stave, you need to decide what the key sig. is going to be, and to me no # or b fits better. At the end of the song, you'll find one particular chord will sound like it fits better than any other. That'll be the decider for the piece's key.

Comment: could it be Eminor?

Comment: It could, I haven't heard it ! C and Am have more in common with Em than Dm does, but that's no great criterion.